# Simple Lightning form Component not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to create a simple form component in Lightning which on load would show all existing values on Database. There's also a Create button which would allow to insert/update.

I've written below code (component , helper and apex controller) but no records are coming up on the section where i intend to show existing records. Could anyone help me where i'm going wrong? Please note that i'm yet to put any code in place for Create button.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="getAccPicklistValues">

<aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" default="{'sObjectType':'Account',
                                                       'Name':'',
                                                       'Industry':'',
                                                       'Phone':''}"/>
<aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]"/>

<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
<div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-col">
            <p class="slds-text-heading--label">Account Creation Page</p>
            <p class="slds-text-heading--small">Enter Account Information</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slds-col slds-col--padded slds-p-top--large">
    <fieldset class="slds-box slds-theme--default slds-container--small">
        <form class="slds-form--stacked">
            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <ui:inputText class="slds-input" label="Account Name" value="{!v.account.Name}" required="true"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <ui:inputSelect class="slds-input" label="Industry" aura:id="inputSelectDynamic" value="{!v.account.Industry}" required="true"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <ui:inputPhone class="slds-input" label="Phone" aura:id="phone" value="{!v.account.Phone}" required="true"/>
                </div>
             </div>
            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <ui:button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" label="Create Account" press="{!c.createAccount}" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="slds-card slds-p-top--medium">
    <header class="slds-card__header">
        <h3 class="slds-text-heading--small">Accounts</h3>
    </header>
    <section class="slds-card__body">
        <div id="list" class="row">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="ac">
                <ui:outputText value="{!ac.Name}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

```
  JS Controller:
  ({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
      helper.getPicklist(component);
      helper.showAccounts(component);
    }
  })

 Helper:
 ({
    getPicklist : function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.getPickListValues");
    var inputsel = component.find("inputSelectDynamic");
    var opts=[];
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log(response.getReturnValue());
        if(state == "SUCCESS"){
            for(var i=0;i< response.getReturnValue().length;i++){
                opts.push({"class": "optionClass", label: response.getReturnValue()[i], value: response.getReturnValue()[i]});
            }
            inputsel.set("v.options", opts);
        }

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
},

showAccounts : function(component){
    var action = component.get("c.getAccounts");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log(response.getReturnValue());
        if(state == "SUCCESS"){
            var accounts = component.get("v.accounts");
            accounts.push(response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.accounts", accounts);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(accounts));
        }

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
}
})

  Class:
  public class getAccPicklistValues{
   @AuraEnabled 
   public static List<String> getPickListValues(){
   List<String> options = new List<String>();
   Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.Industry.getDescribe();
   List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
   for (Schema.PicklistEntry f: ple) {
       options.add(f.getLabel());
   }
   return options;
   }
  @AuraEnabled
   public static List<Account> getAccounts(){
    return[SELECT Name, Industry, Phone FROM Account];
    }
  @AuraEnabled
  public static void createAccount(Account acc){
    upsert acc;
  }
 }
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Nope. Just that i'm not able to see any account records on the component.

Answer (score 0):

It should be component.set("v.accounts",response.getReturnValue()).